# Timeseries in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do timeseries in R for an assignment. I am very new to R and found a video to help me do a times series in R. However, when I read the data set my class is data.frame. I need help changing my dataframe to ts(). this is how my data looks like.

```
year             total
12/31/1984  1932485053
12/31/1985  1983425453
12/31/1986  2036291430
12/31/1987  2090234830
12/31/1988  2146152728
12/31/1989  2201804206
12/31/1990  2259030275
12/31/1991  2315630635
12/31/1992  2370366764
12/31/1993  2427142436
12/31/1994  2483727020
12/31/1995  2542228432
12/31/1996  2599577893
12/31/1997  2657751592
12/31/1998  2716425807
12/31/1999  2775633363
12/31/2000  2835541966
12/31/2001  2899746785
12/31/2002  2967621075

urban = read.csv("urban_test.csv")
plot(urban)
summary(urban)
class(urban)
```

Or help is doing simple timeseries using this data would also be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming `class(df$year)` is `'Date'`, you can do `ts(df$total, start = df$year[1], end = df$year[nrow(df)])`

Comment: Unfortunately my year variable is a factor and struggling to convert it to date    > class(urban$year)
[1] "factor"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `ts(urban$total, start = 1984)`

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame(dates=1001:1010, data=rnorm(10))
str(data)  # It's a data frame

data_ts <- as.ts(data$data)
str(data_ts)  # It's a time series

plot(data_ts)

?ts  # This help might be worth reading
```

You can use the `start` and `end` arguments of `ts` if you wish.